# Convert multidimensional object array to normal array

Tags: angularjs

Hello i know how to get the errors from a laravel validation but now my problem is displaying them. I want a simple way of looping through each error message and displaying on the users page using ng-repeat.

This is a sample of my code:

```
var req = {
    method: 'POST',
    url: '/customer',
    headers: {
        'X-XSRF-Token': $("meta[name='csrf_token']").attr("content")
    },
    data: {
        fullname: $scope.customer.input.fullname,
        address: $scope.customer.input.address,
        telephone: $scope.customer.input.telephone,
        email: $scope.customer.input.email,
        city: $scope.customer.input.city
    }
}

$http(req)
    .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (data.url !== undefined)
        {
            window.location.href = data.url;
        }
    })
    .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        // called asynchronously if an error occurs
        // or server returns response with an error status.
        //alert(data);
    });
```

Example of returned object:

```
{"email":["The email has already been taken.","Email field is required"],"password":["The password must be at least 8 characters
."]}
```

How would i loop through an object like that and display each message vertically on the users page. I use bootstrap css framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the distinct messages into an array and display them as you want:

```
var obj = {"email":["The email has already been taken.","Email field is required"],"password":["The password must be at least 8 characters."]};

var distinctMsgs = [];

for(var prop in obj)
{
   if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
   {
        obj[prop].forEach(function(msg){
            if(distinctMsgs.indexOf(msg) == -1)
            {
                  distinctMsgs.push(msg);
            }
        });
   }
}

console.log(distinctMsgs);
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/whe2b2hj/).